# Is the Belfast Agreement a treaty?

Tags: united-kingdom, ireland, treaty

How does the [Belfast Agreement](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-belfast-agreement)
take legal effect?

Is it a treaty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it’s a [treaty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday_Agreement)

It’s a treaty between the Republic of Ireland and the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland which both countries have given force to in domestic law.

It is also an agreement between eight Northern Irish political parties/groups.

Comment: Is there primary domestic legislation that gives it domestic effect?

Comment: Yes - amendment to the Irish constitution and repeal of a 1920 UK law re Ireland.

Comment: Article 4 specifies the requirements for the text to come to effect including referenda and changes specified above. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/136652/agreement.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There were two separate agreements
the British-Irish Agreement (The Treaty between the UK and Irish Government)
The Multi-Party Agreement (a Multilateral agreement between the UK, Irish Government and NI Parties)
the International Agreement was the First One but its the Second One people refer to as the Belfast/Good Friday Agreement
Any way the Treaty or parts thereof where given effect in the Northern Ireland Act 1998 (c. 47)